# How to delete date space

Tags: spacing

I’m using XeLatex and the document class is `ctexart`. My article don’t need date on it. I tried `\date{}` and `\date{\empty}` and `\date{\vspace{-3em}}`, but they only remove date not including the space. It seems there’s a large space left.

I want to remove the space associated with it. Could you give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Dirty trick: you can use `\date{\vspace{-1cm}}`

Comment: @user94293 Yes I tried, as I mentioned in my question. If we use that, there’s still some space left associated with the date. It doesn’t look nice, is there a way to get rid of that space?

Comment: @user94293 Thanks for your new comment But it still doesn’t work.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @egreg I’m using XeLatex

Comment: @Benny No, I mean what do you use for `\documentclass`. Please add a minimal example of code.

Comment: @egreg sorry. I’m using ctexart.

Comment: I see no added space if I use `\date{}`.

Comment: I know how to do it now. \tittle{The title\vspace{-2ex}} works!

Comment: @Benny - Your latest comment suggests that your document should feature neither `\author` nor `\date`-related information. It would be useful to state this up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redefine the `\maketitle` command

By default it is defined like so

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em
}
```

So if you add a condition to it that would check whether the `\@date` is `\empty`, you will achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{lipsum}             % <=== just for \lipsum dummy text

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
\thispagestyle{empty}           % <=== prevent page numberring on this page
\newpage\null\vskip 2em%
\begin{center}%
    \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
        \lineskip .5em%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
            \@author
        \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    \ifx\@date\empty
        \vspace{-2em}           % <==== change spacing here
    \else
        {\large \@date}%
    \fi
\end{center}%
\par
\vskip 1.5em
}
\makeatother


\title{My title}
\author{Author of the document}

\date{}                 % <=== is empty

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]                      % <=== lipsum dummy text


\end{document}
```

[image]

When `\date` is not empty, for example

```
\date{\today}
```

it works as usual

[image]